# How to : validation summary for kendo Ui dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am currently trying to implement validation summary for my Kendo UI DropDownList when user click btnSubmit. If user selects "Please select" then the validation summary will display error in validation summary said "Please select Product List".

I am unsure how can I do this. Please advise

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

        var pList= $("#ProductList").data("kendoDropDownList").select();

    });
</script>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                        .Name("ProductList")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "width: 130px; margin:0.5em 0 0 0;height:20px;align:center; font-size:11px;" })
                        .OptionLabel("Please Select")
                        .DataTextField("OptionName")
                        .DataValueField("OptionID")
                        .DataSource(source =>
                        {
                            source.Read(read =>
                            {
                                read.Action("GetProduct", "ProductDetails");
                            });
                        })

                )




<div class="submit">
            <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" style="height:50px; width:95px; font-size:13px; background-color: rgb(51, 153, 255); white-space: normal;"  class="k-button" title="Submit" value="Submit" />


        </div>
```

ProductDetailsController.cs

```
public JsonResult GetRole()
            {
                var productName = new ContexEntities();

                return Json(productName.Product.Select(c => new { OptionID = c.OptionID, OptionName = c.OptionName, OptionTypeID = c.ConfigTypeID })
                    .OrderBy(c => c.OptionName).Where(e => e.OptionTypeID == 10), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML or Razor:**

```razor
<div id="ValidateMyContents">
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                    .Name("ProductList")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new {required = "required", data_required_msg = "Selection Required", @Style = "width: 130px; margin:0.5em 0 0 0;height:20px;align:center; font-size:11px;" })
                    .OptionLabel("Please Select")
                    .DataTextField("OptionName")
                    .DataValueField("OptionID")
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("GetProduct", "ProductDetails");
                        });
                    })

            )
        <span id="status"></span>
        <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
 </div>
```

---

**Script:**

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var validator = $("#ValidateMyContents").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator"),
        status = $(".status");

    $("btnSubmit").click(function () {
        if (validator.validate()) {
            status.text("Hooray!");
        } else {
            status.text("Oops! There is invalid data in the form.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

---

**Reference:** [Kendo ui validator Demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/validator/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I added this style:

```
.k-dropdown-clientValidation input[type='text'] {
    height: 0;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: -99;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -26px !important;
    display:  block !important;
    border-style: none !important;
}
```

And then Razor looks like this:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                    .Name("ProductList")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class="k-dropdown-clientValidation", @Style = "width: 130px; margin:0.5em 0 0 0;height:20px;align:center; font-size:11px;" })
                    .OptionLabel("Please Select")
                    .DataTextField("OptionName")
                    .DataValueField("OptionID")
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("GetProduct", "ProductDetails");
                        });
                    })

            )
```

This basically unhides the input and moves it up behind the dropdownlist.  You might have to play around with the style a little. We display the validation message above the control so the style works for us.