# Kendo ui dropdownlist validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

```
<%= Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("ScheduleNumber1")
    .DataTextField("ScheduleNumber")
    .DataValueField("ScheduleNumber")
    //  .Filter("contains")
    .DataSource(source => {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetScheduleNumber1", "Ticket");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(false);
    })
    .OptionLabel("Please Select")
%>
```

I am using kendo dropdownlist in my asp.net mvc problem can you tell me how to add required validation when Please select is selected i am not able to find how to add validation my model validation is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554731/how-to-validation-summary-for-kendo-ui-dropdownlist) to your problem, easy and straight forward. But its going bit around, eg not using the build in MVC wrapper which should do it for you.

Reality is (at least it sounds like) this functionality is not supported out of the box at the moment, which is quite a surprise.

Here is a whole [thread](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/validation/using-kendo-validator-with-mvc-model-properties.aspx) talking about this issue, with recommended solution :

```
(function ($, kendo) {
    $.extend(true, kendo.ui.validator, {
        rules: {
            mvcrequired: function (input) {            
                if (input.filter("[data-val-required]").length) {
                    var value = input.val();
                    return !(value === "" || !value);
                }
                return true;
            }
        },
        messages: { 
            mvcrequired: function (input) {
                return input.attr("data-val-required");
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery, kendo);
```

I am sure you had a look [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/validation).